Can I screenshot my nodes in Blender 4.0?
I need a high-resolution image of my nodes in GN in Blender 4.0.
I tried using print nodes but it doesn't work with blender 4.0 and some of the nodes are missing from the Blender versions that print nodes work with.

You can go full screen by hovering over the node editor and hitting Ctrl-Space but it depends how large your node group is as to whether it will fit in the space and be readable. Use Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu to save an image.

I think you can easily with the AltGr and Print keys together, so you take a photo of the screen you use however you want, even with Paint.

If you have access to Photoshop, you can take a bunch of overlapping screenshots and auto align and merge them in Photoshop quickly and easily. Not sure if that can easily(not manually) be done in other software like Gimp or Krita though unfortunately.

Nope, that doesn't seem to work well actually after I tested it, I think the background and the nodes are too repetitive for Photoshop to stitch them automatically especially if same nodes repeat...

OK, so this is not the proper way to do it, but the fastest I could get it to work was the following.
So it fails to import PIL from the add-on's folder. OK... I have no idea what's going on and don't want to find out, let's just install PIL to Blender's Python directly(not the right way, right? Someone please feel free to correct this.)
So I find the Python in C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\python\bin and I launch command prompt as administrator:

I then run
"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\python\bin\python.exe" -m pip install Pillow
OK, got PIL now in Blender's Python so I can change
from .PIL import ...

to
from PIL import ...

In the add-on. Amazing. Only it's not. The add-on will not work without this huge hassle now... Anyway...
Now you can save this butchered version of the add-on as a .py file from Blender's Text Editor(it saves in correct text encoding) and install it as an add-on. And it seems to work for Geometry Nodes only and only for all nodes in 4.1 on Windows:
bl_info = {
    "name" : "PrintNodes",
    "author" : "Binit, Martynas Žiemys",
    "description" : "Takes high quality screenshot of a node tree",
    "blender" : (4, 1, 0),
    "version" : (1, 1, 2),
    "location" : "Node Editor > Context Menu (Right Click)",
    "warning" : "",
    "category" : "Node"
}

import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator, AddonPreferences, Menu
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty, IntProperty

import time
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageChops, ImageOps


def MakeDirectory(): # Manage Directory for saving screenshots

    if bpy.data.filepath and bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences.force_secondary_dir == False: 
        # save image in the place where the blendfile is saved, in a newly created subfolder (if saved and force_default_directory is set to false)
        Directory = os.path.join(os.path.split(bpy.data.filepath)[0], 'NodesShots')
        
        if os.path.isdir(Directory) == False:
            os.mkdir(Directory)
            bpy.ops.wm
    else:  
        # just use the secondary directory otherwise
        Directory = bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences.secondary_save_dir

    return Directory


class PRTND_PT_Preferences(AddonPreferences): # setting up perferences
    bl_idname = __name__

    secondary_save_dir: StringProperty(
        name = "Secondary Directory",
        subtype = 'DIR_PATH',
        default = bpy.context.preferences.filepaths.temporary_directory,
        )

    force_secondary_dir: BoolProperty(
        name = "Always Use Secondary Directory",
        default = False,
        )

    padding_amount: IntProperty(
        name = "Padding Amount (in px)",
        default = 30,
        )
    crop: IntProperty(
        name = "Crop Tiles",
        default = 40,
        )

    disable_auto_crop: BoolProperty(
        name = 'Disable Auto Cropping',
        description = 'Check this if something is not working properly',
        default = False,
        )

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text = "A subfolder in the same directory as the blend file will be used to save the images.")
        layout.label(text = "Unless the file is unsaved or 'Always Use Secondary Directory' is checked.")
        layout.label(text = "In whcich case, the Secondary Directory will be used")
        layout.prop(self, "secondary_save_dir")
        layout.prop(self, "force_secondary_dir")
        layout.separator()
        layout.prop(self, "padding_amount")
        layout.prop(self, "disable_auto_crop")
        layout.prop(self, "crop")


class PRTND_MT_ContextMenu(Menu): 
    """Context Menu For Print Nodes"""
    bl_idname = "PRTND_MT_context_menu"
    bl_label = "PrintNodes"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator(PRTND_OT_ModalScreenshotTimer.bl_idname, text = "Take Screenshot Of Whole Tree", icon = "NODETREE")
        layout.operator(PRTND_OT_ModalScreenshotTimer.bl_idname, text = "Take Screenshot Of Selected Nodes", icon = "SELECT_SET").selection_only = True


def PrintNodesPopUp(message = "", title = "PrintNodes PopUp", icon = ""): # function to display popup message on command

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.label(text = message)

    bpy.context.window_manager.popup_menu(draw, title = title, icon = icon)


class PRTND_OT_ModalScreenshotTimer(Operator): # modal operator to take parts of the whole shot every at every set interval, while not interrupting the rest of blender's functioning (for the most part)
    """Take screenshot of active node tree. Press RightClick or Esc to cancel during process."""
    bl_idname = "prtnd.modal_ss_timer"
    bl_label = "Take Tree Screenshot"

    selection_only: BoolProperty(default = False)

    _timer = None
    Xmin = Ymin = Xmax = Ymax = 0
    ix = iy = 0
    temp_name = ''
    temp_grid_level = 0
    forced_cancel = False


    def modal(self, context, event): 
        crop = bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences.crop
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}: # force cancel
            self.forced_cancel = True
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
                  
            tree = context.space_data.edit_tree
            view = context.region.view2d
            area = bpy.context.area
            dx = area.width
            dy = area.height
            
            path = os.path.join(MakeDirectory(), f'Prt_y{self.iy}_x{self.ix}.png')
            #bpy.ops.screen.screenshot(filepath=path) # take screenshot of current view as a 'tile' to be further stitched and processed
            bpy.ops.screen.screenshot_area(filepath=path,hide_props_region=True,)
            if tree.view_center[1] > self.Ymax and tree.view_center[0] > self.Xmax: # check if already at the other corner of the tree, if yes, sucessfully terminate
                self.cancel(context)
                return {'CANCELLED'}
            
            if tree.view_center[0] > self.Xmax: # if exceeded rightmost edge, pan all the way back to leftmost edge and pan y up once to prepare for the next 'layer' of tiles
                bpy.ops.view2d.pan(deltax = -(self.ix*(dx-(crop*2))), deltay=dy-(crop*2))
                self.ix = 0
                self.iy += 1

            else: # just pan to the right if no other condition applies (i.e. we're somewhere in the middle of the tile strip)
                bpy.ops.view2d.pan(deltax = dx-(crop*2), deltay =0)
                self.ix += 1

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'} # pass for next iteration

    def execute(self, context):
        
        invisible_ascii_char = 'Рађ' # magically invisible ascii character for super secret reasons (which is, so that the material label on the screen doesn't appear and mess up the shot)

        self.temp_name = context.space_data.id.name
        context.space_data.id.name = invisible_ascii_char

        self.temp_grid_level = context.preferences.themes[0].node_editor.grid_levels
        bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].node_editor.grid_levels = 0 # turn gridlines off, trimming empty space doesn't work otherwise

        if self.selection_only:
            nodes = context.selected_nodes # perform within the selected nodes only
        else:  
            nodes = context.space_data.node_tree.nodes # perform within the whole tree
        tree = context.space_data.node_tree

        self.Xmin = self.Xmax = nodes[0].location[0]
        self.Ymin = self.Ymax = nodes[0].location[1]
    

        for i in range(len(nodes)):
            loc = nodes[i].location
            locX = loc[0]
            locY = loc[1]
            
            if locX < self.Xmin:
                self.Xmin = locX
            if locY < self.Ymin:
                self.Ymin = locY

            if locX > self.Xmax:
                self.Xmax = locX
            if locY > self.Ymax:
                self.Ymax = locY
            
        node = tree.nodes.new("NodeReroute") # new reroute node as guide for the algorithm to work
        node.location = self.Xmin, self.Ymin

        for current_node in nodes:
            current_node.select = False
        
        node.select = True
        bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(iterations=1) # Force Updates 2dview so that the ndoe location gets updated. this one ugly line makes the whole addone uncompatible for being an official addon, may find a workaround later. But gotta live with it for now
        bpy.ops.node.view_selected() # align view to the (bottom-left) corner node. As an initial point for the screenshotting process
        
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.2, window=context.window) # add timer to begin with, for the `modal` process
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):

        if self.forced_cancel: 
            PrintNodesPopUp(message = "Process Force Cancelled", icon = "CANCEL")

        else:
            area = bpy.context.area
            StitchTiles(area.width, area.height, self.ix + 1, self.iy + 1) # being the stitching and processing process of the tiles
            PrintNodesPopUp(message = "Screenshot Saved Successfully", icon = "CHECKMARK")

        # revert all the temporary settings back to original
        context.preferences.themes[0].node_editor.grid_levels = self.temp_grid_level
        context.space_data.id.name = self.temp_name

        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)


def TrimImage(img): # function to trim out empty space from the edges, leaving a padding (as defined in preferences)

    bg_clr = tuple(bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].node_editor.space.back * 255) # get the background color of the shader editor from themes and map from 0-1 to 0-255 for PIL operations
    bg_clr = tuple(map(lambda i: int(i), bg_clr)) # convert float tuple to int tuple (as Image.new(color) expectes Int tuple)

    padding = bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences.padding_amount
    padding_tuple = (-padding, -padding, padding, padding) # to subtract padding amount from x_min, y_min and add to x_max, y_max for cropping
    
    img_w, img_h = img.size
    img_size_tuple = (img_w, img_h, img_w, img_h) # tuple of image size in format (x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max) for clamping padding amount, with some 'hacky' elements


    bg = Image.new(img.mode, img.size, bg_clr)
    diff = ImageChops.difference(img, bg)
    bbox = diff.getbbox()

    crop_tuple = tuple(map(lambda i, j: i + j, bbox, padding_tuple)) # offset the co-ords to leave space for padding
    crop_tuple = tuple(map(lambda i, j: max(0, min(i, j)), crop_tuple, img_size_tuple)) # clamp all values to not be outside the image (negative or greater than size of image)

    if bbox:
        return img.crop(crop_tuple)
    else:
        return img


def StitchTiles(tile_width, tile_height, num_x, num_y): # function to stitch multiple tiles to one single image
    crop = bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences.crop
    folder_path = MakeDirectory()
    tile_width = tile_width - crop*2
    tile_height = tile_height - crop*2
    out_canvas = Image.new('RGB', (tile_width * num_x, tile_height * num_y))

    for y in range(num_y):
        for x in range(num_x):
            tile_path = os.path.join(folder_path, f'Prt_y{y}_x{x}.png')
            current_tile = Image.open(tile_path)
            current_tile = ImageOps.crop(current_tile, crop)
            out_canvas.paste(current_tile, (tile_width * x, tile_height * (num_y - (y + 1))))
            os.remove(tile_path) #remove used tiles

    if not bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences.disable_auto_crop:
        out_canvas = TrimImage(out_canvas)

    timestamp = time.strftime("%y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    out_path = os.path.join(folder_path, f'NodeTreeShot{timestamp}.png')
    out_canvas.save(out_path)



# menu function(s)
def PrintNodes_menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.menu(PRTND_MT_ContextMenu.bl_idname, icon="FCURVE_SNAPSHOT")

classes = (PRTND_OT_ModalScreenshotTimer, PRTND_PT_Preferences, PRTND_MT_ContextMenu, )

#addon_keymaps = []


def register():

    for current in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(current)

    bpy.types.NODE_MT_context_menu.append(PrintNodes_menu_func)

    # wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    # kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    # if kc:
    #     km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Node Editor', space_type='NODE_EDITOR')
    #     kmi = km.keymap_items.new(PRTND_OT_ModalScreenshotTimer.bl_idname, 'C', 'PRESS', ctrl=True, shift=True)
    #     addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))

def unregister():

    for current in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(current)

    bpy.types.NODE_MT_context_menu.remove(PrintNodes_menu_func)

    # for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
    #     km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    # addon_keymaps.clear()

I added this Crop tiles setting that you can adjust in the add-on's preferences:


So if I saw an answer like this I would judge it. May even down-vote... But it's at least a way to get the screenshot. :D

I got this error in the Cmd:- E:>E:\Program Files\blender\4.1\python\bin  -m pip install Pillow
'E:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Copy paste more gently. It's ... \Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\python\bin\python.exe" -m pip install Pillow you did not include 'python.exe' at the end. Also there are quotes for the path because it includes space character.

i couldn't get it to work idk how and why

I tested it a few times and I just re-tested. It works in Blender 4.1 on Windows 11. If you follow the steps correctly.

Type "import PIL" in Python console in Blender to see if it got installed. You should not get any errors.

Else than that, maybe try contacting the developer, show this answer to him and hopefully he will be shocked and disgusted by this solution and will fix it properly.
